# Difference between using the uniq command with sort or without it in linux

Tags: linux, shell, sorting, command, uniq

When I use `uniq -u data.txt` lists the whole file and when I use `sort data.txt | uniq -u` it omits repeated lines. Why does this happen?
`uniq` man says that -u, --unique only prints unique lines. I don't understand why I need to use pipe to get correct output.

Comment: [Cross-site duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536775/uniq-command-not-working-properly)

Comment: How about `sort -u data.txt`? The `-u` flag applies uniqueness.

Comment: with `sort -u data.txt` i get the same result with `uniq -u data.txt`. For me only works `sort data.txt | uniq -u`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uniq` removes **adjacent** duplicates. If you want to omit duplicates that are **not** adjacent, you'll have to sort the data first.

Comment: Ok thx, my bad. Im continue reading the man info and said just this Note: 'uniq' does not detect  repeated lines unless they are adjacent. You may want to sort input first, or use 'sort -u' without 'uniq'. 
Next time i will finish reading the man before asking. Sorry mate.